# com.google.ar.core.exceptions.NotYetAvailableException on frame.acquireCameraImage()

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception, arcore

**Case 1:** This is the code

```
private void onUpdateListener(FrameTime frameTime) {
    try
    {
        Frame frame = nodeArFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();

        if (frame == null) {
            return;
        }

        computingDetection = true;


        Image androidMediaImage = frame.acquireCameraImage();

        Bitmap rotatedImage = Utilities.getBitmap(androidMediaImage,detector);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedImage);

        new Thread(() -> {
            List<Classifier.Recognition> results = null;

              results = detector.recognizeImage(rotatedImage);

      //  drawBoxes(results);
        }).start();

    } catch (NotYetAvailableException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "NotYetAvailableException", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DeadlineExceededException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "DeadlineExceededException", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

When this is the code, I'm getting this error

```
FAILED_PRECONDITION: 
    ARCoreError: third_party/arcore/ar/core/cpu_image_manager.cc:252
     [type.googleapis.com/util.ErrorSpacePayload='ArStatusErrorSpace::AR_ERROR_NOT_YET_AVAILABLE']
2020-11-21 06:53:23.389 24361-24361/com.example.nodetypesarcore E/ContentValues: NotYetAvailableException
    com.google.ar.core.exceptions.NotYetAvailableException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

**Case 2:**
When I removed the thread, I get the error for the first frame, but it doesn't stop the application and continues to work from the next frame! But in the previous case, the application stops on receiving that error!

```
    try
    {
        Frame frame = nodeArFragment.getArSceneView().getArFrame();

        if (frame == null) {
            return;
        }

        computingDetection = true;


        Image androidMediaImage = frame.acquireCameraImage();

        Bitmap rotatedImage = Utilities.getBitmap(androidMediaImage,detector);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(rotatedImage);

        List<Classifier.Recognition> results = null;

        results = detector.recognizeImage(rotatedImage);

     
    } catch (NotYetAvailableException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "NotYetAvailableException", e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DeadlineExceededException e){
        Log.e(TAG, "DeadlineExceededException", e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But if I remove the thread, it's very laggy but it works as expected. So how do I have a thread and avoid the error? Thank you!

Comment: I'm stuck with the same error. Any workaround yet?

Comment: I had the same error when directly referencing the `androidMediaImage`. After physically copying the image data to a bitmap the issue went away.

Is the `Utilities.getBitmap` function copying the image information?

Additionally I would recommend calling the `close` function to clean up the image after use. In the long run, this could result in AR_ERROR_RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED.

Comment: could you please share Utilities.getBitmap(androidMediaImage,detector); this function.